# Trivial specialization of a method does not work (c++)

Tags: c++, methods, hyperlink, specialization

The following code (this is a simplified version of what I need) does not link

In *.h file:

```
class InterfaceFunctionField2 {
public:
    template<class outputType> outputType to() { return outputType(); }
};
```

In *.cpp file

```
template<> double InterfaceFunctionField2::to<double>()
{    return 3.;  }
```

This class sits in a static library.

I am getting "error LNK2005: "public: double __thiscall InterfaceFunctionField2::to(void)const " (??$to@N@InterfaceFunctionField2@@QBENXZ) already defined in  ..." and a "second definition ignored" warning LNK4006

I define InterfaceFunctionField2::to() specialization only once and I do not #include *.cpp files....

I have looked up on internet ([e.g. here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t291707-full-specialization-of-template-member-function.html)) and this type of code seems to be ok but the linker disagrees. Could you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also declare the specialization in the header.

```
//header.h
class InterfaceFunctionField2 {
public:
    template<class outputType> outputType to() { return outputType(); }
};

template<> double InterfaceFunctionField2::to<double>();

//implementation.cc
template<> double InterfaceFunctionField2::to<double>()
{    return 3.;  }
```

The code in your link works because the specialization is visible to that translation unit.

Comment: Correct answer in less than a minute after the question was posted! Very impressive, many thanks.